# Frontier Justice questions

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

I have a few questions regarding how the new frontier justice shotgun for the engineer works, especially regarding death:

1. If you have X revenge crits remaining and you die, do you respawn with any revenge crits ready?
2. If your sentry gets destroyed while you're dead, do you get any revenge crits?
3. If you have X revenge crits remaining, you build another sentry and then it gets destroyed, what happens to your remaining crits? Are they replaced with the crits you should have gotten from the newly-destroyed ones, do you get them as a bonus, or what?

Can anyone with any experience with this weapon help me with the above questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. If you die you will lose all Revenge Crits
2. If you sentry is destroyed while dead you will not get Revenge Crits <strike>(90% sure but this evening I will test it)</strike>
3. If you build/destroy other sentries all Revenge Crits are accumulated, until you die or for a maximum of 35 revenge crits. There is no way to lose Revenge Crits while alive, the only one is use them or switch your weapon to old shotugun! :)

Comment: You do not get revenge crits if your sentry dies and you are dead.

Comment: On the other hand, if you die, respawn, and THEN your sentry is destroyed, you will recieve revenge crits so long as you are alive while your sentry is destroyed.